# How do you use badblocks?

Tags: filesystems, hardware, badblocks

I need to do a destructive (rw) test on a new drive, and a read-only on a drive that fell out of my RAID array. I want to see if it finds problems and how far along it is.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Let `/dev/sda` be the new drive on which to test destructive-rw and `/dev/sdb` the old drive where you want non-destructive-r

```
# badblocks -wsv /dev/sda
# badblocks -sv /dev/sdb
```

`-s` gives the process indicator

`-v` gives verbose output

`-w` enables destructive read-write

`-n` would be non-destructive read-write

Read-only testing is the default and doesn't need special parameters.

Comment: You might want to add the use the "-o output_file" option for badblocks as well because it writes the bad sectors into a file which you can pass to `mke2fs` or `e2fsck` to make those tools aware of which blocks are broken.

Comment: @tante is right without "-o output_file" the results are just output to the screen, unusable by e2fsck.  The badblocks man page however recommends that you run "e2fsck -c" instead of utilizing badblocks -o, to avoid possible block size mismatch, fwiw...